# What does "unused receiver parameter" in IntelliJ mean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, warnings

After the upgrade to IntelliJ 2020.2 we do get a warning *Redundant suppression* if we have

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static Stream<Arguments> findExportKonfiguration() {
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of("Konfiguration 1", HrdfFormat.HRDF_52039, 1),
        Arguments.of("Konfiguration 2", HrdfFormat.HRDF_54041, 1),
        Arguments.of("Konfiguration 3", HrdfFormat.HRDF_52039, 1),
        Arguments.of("Konfiguration 1", null, 1),
        Arguments.of(null, HrdfFormat.HRDF_52039, 2),
        Arguments.of(null, null, 3)
    );
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource
public void findExportKonfiguration(String bezeichnung, HrdfFormat hrdfFormat, int size) {
    TestTransaction.start();
    // ....
}
```

Until now this was necessary, since IntelliJ does not regocnise that the Method belongs to a `@ParametrizedTest` with `@MethodSource`.

The *Redundant suppression* warning is caused by an option called *unused receiver parameter*. What does that mean? The IntelliJ help page has no inforation about this option.

Comment: Please add to the issue how does the method with `@MethodSource` annotation look like. There was a number of fixes that allow for "method source" method being resolved, so probably that's why "unused declaration" inspection doesn't report anymore and suppression not needed.

Comment: Added the method. Unfortunately IntelliJ 2020.2 still reports this as unused code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is already fixed in IntelliJ IDEA v2020.3 (not released yet). Please see the report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203748